# Combinatorics - football match

Tags: combinatorics

I get two numbers - guests and home. E. g. guests is 3 and home is 2 so the result of the footbal match is 3:2. I need to find a formula how to find a number of all possible developments of the match. So if the result of the match is 3:2 the match could go like this: 0:0 - 0:1 - 1:1 - 2:1 - 2:2 - 3:2 but it could also go like this: 0:0 - 0:1 - 0:2 - 1:2 - 2:2 - 3:2 etc.

What is the formula to find a number of all possible developments of the match for any given numbers as guests and home?

I know that I have to use binomial coefficients but I do not know how.

Answer (score 1):

For a result $j:k$, you need to choose $j$ out of $j+k$ slots in which the $j$ guest goals were scored. Thus there are $\binom{j+k}j$ different possible developments.

Answer (score 1):

Let the final score of guests vs home be $x:y$

Note that at each stage, either guests could score $(+1:+0)$ or home could score $(+0:+1)$. Let $G$ and $H$ denote the guests scoring and home scoring respectively. The number of permutations will be the number of ways in which $x$ G's and $y$ H's can be arranged in a sequence. This is given as

$$P=\frac {(x+y)!}{x!\times y!}$$